# В чём практическая ценность функции vec?

Tags: perl

Функция **vec**, для чего она нужна и где без неё нельзя обойтись *в принципе*?

Comment: Примерно для того же, для чего в C можно в структурах делать битовые поля (которые с двоеточием). Обойтись без нее можно везде. Битами можно так же управлять битовыми операциями или формировать нужные байты с помощью pack/unpack. Просто с ней с битами работать проще

Answer (score 0):

Описание:

```
vec EXPR, OFFSET, BITS
```

Эта функция использует указанную строку EXPR как вектор целых чисел без знака. Параметр NUMBITS - это количество бит, зарезервированных для каждой записи в битовом векторе.

Обратите внимание, что смещение является маркером для конца вектора, и оно подсчитывает количество бит, указанное для поиска начала. Векторы могут управляться логическими побитовыми операторами |, & и ^.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$vec = '';
vec($vec,  3, 4) = 1;  # bits 0 to 3
vec($vec,  7, 4) = 10; # bits 4 to 7
vec($vec, 11, 4) = 3;  # bits 8 to 11
vec($vec, 15, 4) = 15; # bits 12 to 15
print("vec(), in hex: ", unpack("h*", $vec), "\n");
```

Результат:

```
vec(), in hex: 0001000a0003000f
```